Train lfw dataset, metric learning
I'm trying to train a model to compare faces using the library pytorch-metric-learning.
I based this example from https://github.com/KevinMusgrave/pytorch-metric-learning/blob/master/examples/notebooks/TripletMarginLossMNIST.ipynb
I tried different samplers miners and losses but the model is not trained.Please tell me where I'm wrong. I'm new to metric training
Thanks for any help!
import pytorch_metric_learning as pml
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torchvision.models import resnet18, ResNet18_Weights
from torchvision.models import mobilenet_v3_large, MobileNet_V3_Large_Weights
from torchvision.models import mobilenet_v3_small, MobileNet_V3_Small_Weights
import torchvision
import cv2
from pytorch_metric_learning import distances, losses, miners, reducers, testers,samplers
from pytorch_metric_learning.utils.accuracy_calculator import AccuracyCalculator
import numpy as np
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR

class CFG:
    nepoch = 200
    batch_size = 256
    device="cuda"
    dataset_dir = "./tmp"
    sampler_m = 2
    learning_rate = 0.001
    weight_decay = 0.0005
    step_size = 50
    gamma = 0.5
    num_workers = 16



class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.model = mobilenet_v3_small(weights = MobileNet_V3_Small_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1)
        self.model.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            self.model.classifier[0],
            nn.Linear(1024,512, bias = True),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25),
            #nn.ReLU(),
            #nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
            nn.Linear(512,256, bias = True),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.2),
            nn.Linear(256,128, bias = True)
        )
        print(self.model)

    def forward(self,x):
        y = self.model(x)
        return y
    

def get_all_embeddings(dataset, model):
    tester = testers.BaseTester()
    return tester.get_all_embeddings(dataset, model)

def grid_image(batch):
    grid_imgs = torchvision.utils.make_grid(batch,normalize=True)
    grid_imgs = (grid_imgs * 255).cpu().numpy().astype(dtype = np.uint8)
    grid_imgs = np.transpose(grid_imgs,(1,2,0))
    grid_imgs = cv2.cvtColor(grid_imgs,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    return grid_imgs

def step_iterio(model,optimizer,loss_func,mining_func,inputs,labes):
    data, labels = inputs.cuda(),labes.cuda()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    embeddings = model(data)
    indices_tuple = mining_func(embeddings, labels)
    loss = loss_func(embeddings, labels, indices_tuple)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()


def train_lfw():
    cfg = CFG()
    #cfg.batch_size = 16
    # configure dataset 
    t_train = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((224,224)),
        transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=(0.5,1.5)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])

    t_test = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((224,224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])
    # dataset configure
    dataset_train = datasets.LFWPeople(cfg.dataset_dir,split = "train",transform = t_train)
    dataset_test = datasets.LFWPeople(cfg.dataset_dir,split = "test",transform = t_test)
    sampler = samplers.MPerClassSampler(dataset_train.targets,m=cfg.sampler_m,batch_size=cfg.batch_size,length_before_new_iter=10000)
    dataloader_train = DataLoader(dataset_train,batch_size=cfg.batch_size,sampler=sampler,num_workers=cfg.num_workers)

    #idx_to_class = {v:k for k,v in dataset_train.class_to_idx.items()}

    model = Net()
    model.cuda()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=cfg.learning_rate,weight_decay=cfg.weight_decay)
    lr_sheduler = StepLR(optimizer,step_size=cfg.step_size,gamma=cfg.gamma)
    #mining_func = miners.PairMarginMiner()
    #loss_func = losses.ContrastiveLoss(pos_margin=0.5,neg_margin=0.5)
    distance = distances.LpDistance()
    reducer = reducers.MeanReducer()
    loss_func = losses.TripletMarginLoss(margin=0.5, distance=distance, reducer=reducer)

    mining_func = miners.TripletMarginMiner(margin=0.5, distance=distance, type_of_triplets="all")

    accuracy_calculator = AccuracyCalculator(include=("precision_at_1",), k=1)
    for epoch in range(cfg.nepoch):
        model.train()
        for i_batch, (data, labels) in enumerate(dataloader_train):
            # print(labels)
            # for l in labels:
            #     print(l," ",idx_to_class[l.item()])
            data, labels = data.cuda(),labels.cuda()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            embeddings = model(data)

            indices_tuple = mining_func(embeddings, labels)
            # print(indices_tuple[0])
            # print(indices_tuple[1])
            # print(indices_tuple[2])
            # print(labels)
            loss = loss_func(embeddings, labels, indices_tuple)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            if i_batch % 10 == 0:
                print(
                    "Epoch {} Iteration {}: Loss = {}".format(
                        epoch, i_batch, loss
                    )
                )
            # grid_imgs = grid_image(data)
            # print(labels)
            # cv2.imshow("grid_imgs",grid_imgs)
            # cv2.waitKey()
            #break
        # testing
        lr_sheduler.step()
        model.eval()
        test_embeddings, test_labels = get_all_embeddings(dataset_test, model)
        #test_embeddings, test_labels = get_all_embeddings(dataset_train, model)
        test_labels = test_labels.squeeze(1)
        accuracies = accuracy_calculator.get_accuracy(test_embeddings, test_labels)
        print("Test set accuracy (Precision@1) = {}".format(accuracies["precision_at_1"]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    train_lfw()


Did you check you had the gradient flowing properly from the output to the parameters of the model?

How to check it process?

First, check embeddings.grad_fn

I apologize for not answering for a very long time. I don't quite understand what I'm supposed to see there. I did everything as shown in the tutorials.

Did you check that?
